# Hiding block from top to bottom

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, animation

I have a filter , on click I'm hiding it. It has transition property and it goes from BOTTOM to TOP . I have recorded my screen , you can check it here https://pics.rocketfirm.com/jamilya/Screencast_14-48_13-08-2019.mp4 . The problem is I need to hide it from TOP to BOTTOM. Making same thing but opposite way , ending up when filter button shows up .

```
.filter-block {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 20px 0 1px;
  position: relative;
  transition: max-height 0.5s ease, padding 0.5s ease 0.3s;

  > .container {
    transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in 0.2s;
    opacity: 1;
  }
&--hide {
    max-height: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    > .container {
      transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
      opacity: 0;
    }
  }
}

<div className={cn('filter-block', {
   'filter-block--hide ': !showMainFilter
 })}> code inside </div>
```

Comment: Please provide working example, video isn't enough to help you

Comment: You can try giving the element a absolute position and setting a bottom property. Then if you animate height it will expand up. Side note, you can give the element ;s parent a relative position to minimize the impact of absolute postioning

Answer (score -1):

```js
$('.shide').click(function(){
    $(this).next().slideToggle();
});
```

```css
.slidediv {
    height:300px;
    background-color: red;
    color: #fff;
    padding:20px;
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="shide">Show/hide</div>
<div class="slidediv">
Hi Man. </div>
```

Look at: http://jsfiddle.net/uniak/249ybqgv/